# PHP dropping decimals without rounding up

Tags: php, decimal, rounding

I want to drop off decimals without rounding up. For example if I have 1.505, I want to drop last decimal and value should be 1.50. Is there such a function in PHP?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need [floor()](http://php.net/floor) in this way:

```
$rounded = floor($float*100)/100;
```

Or you cast to integer:

```
$rounded = 0.01 * (int)($float*100);
```

This way it will not be rounding up.

Comment: Works fine unless the trailing 0 in the example is a requirement.

Comment: For negative values, use ceil() instead of floor()

Comment: this is not a complete solution UNLESS you _only_ have positive numbers - you need to use BOTH `floor()` and `ceil()` if you don't know the sign of the number you are rounding - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28821326/3092596)

Comment: This is not an absolutely correct solution. `floor(5.1*100)/100;` yields `5.09`, instead of expected `5.10`. You can try with 5.100, or 4.1 the same incorrect result.

Comment: Like @MuhammedM. said, it doesn't work accurately all the time, like this case: `floor(19.99 * 100)` returns `1998` instead of `1999`. This should not be the correct answer

Comment: It didn't worked correctly for say example input: 2581.68. It returns "2581.67", however expected return value is "2581.68".

Comment: You can use my solution with preg_replace to avoid all of the issues above. It just treats it like a string, cuts it and puts it back as a number. See answer further down.

Comment: Use intval() rather than floor().

Answer (score 17):

Use the PHP native function [bcdiv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php)

```
echo bcdiv(2.56789, 1, 2);  // 2.56
```

Comment: Perfect. Used it to get 2 digit and applied number_format with 2 to properly show my price. Thanks

Comment: `bcdiv()` does require the [https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php](BCMath) PHP extension. Most PHP versions have it enabled by default. To check if your PHP has it enabled, look for "BCMath support => enabled" in the output of `phpinfo()` or `$ php -i | grep BCMath`

Answer (score 12):

To do this accurately for both +ve ***and*** -ve numbers you need use:
- the php `floor()` function for +ve numbers
- the php `ceil()` function for -ve numbers

```
function truncate_float($number, $decimals) {
    $power = pow(10, $decimals); 
    if($number > 0){
        return floor($number * $power) / $power; 
    } else {
        return ceil($number * $power) / $power; 
    }
}
```

the reason for this is that `floor()` always rounds the number ***down***, not towards zero.
ie `floor()` effectively rounds -ve numbers *towards a larger absolute value*
eg `floor(1.5) = 1` while `floor(-1.5) = -2`

Therefore, for the `multiply by power, remove decimals, divide by power` truncate method :
- `floor()` only works for positive numbers
- `ceil()` only works for negative numbers

To test this, copy the following code into the editor of http://phpfiddle.org/lite (or similar):

```
<div>Php Truncate Function</div>
<br>
<?php
    function truncate_float($number, $places) {
        $power = pow(10, $places); 
        if($number > 0){
            return floor($number * $power) / $power; 
        } else {
            return ceil($number * $power) / $power; 
        }
    }

    // demo
    $lat = 52.4884;
    $lng = -1.88651;
    $lat_tr = truncate_float($lat, 3);
    $lng_tr = truncate_float($lng, 3);
    echo 'lat = ' . $lat . '<br>';
    echo 'lat truncated = ' . $lat_tr . '<br>';
    echo 'lat = ' . $lng . '<br>';
    echo 'lat truncated = ' . $lng_tr . '<br><br>';

    // demo of floor() on negatives
    echo 'floor (1.5) = ' . floor(1.5) . '<br>';
    echo 'floor (-1.5) = ' . floor(-1.5) . '<br>';
?>
```

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: For 18.31 this gives me 18.3

Answer (score 11):

```
$float = 1.505;

echo sprintf("%.2f", $float);

//outputs 1.50
```

Comment: Works beautifully when combined with typecasting `(float) $float` if you're continuing to use this in calculations.

Comment: It's important to note that `sprintf` will ROUND floats if it thinks it needs to. For example, take the division `31 / 53 = 0.584905[...]` - if we want 3 decimal places, we can do `sprintf("%.3f", (31 / 53))` but this does NOT give us 0.584. It gives us 0.585.

Comment: sprintf rounds the value... sprintf('%.2f', '1.239') => 1.24

Comment: It is expected without rounding... 5.555 should be 5.55 not. 5.56

Comment: This is not the answer. sprintf does round the value.

Comment: Also, `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.  This answer is not lying, however, that it provides the desired result from the sample input: https://3v4l.org/PQoKW  Jamie is not wrong either -- https://3v4l.org/h37XV  and Loenix is correct as well https://3v4l.org/SsNUb . So it seems this technique is not reliable.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's too late, but here's a good approach:

```
    $getTruncatedValue = function( $value, $precision )
    {
        //Casts provided value
        $value = ( string )$value;

        //Gets pattern matches
        preg_match( "/(-+)?\d+(\.\d{1,".$precision."})?/" , $value, $matches );

        //Returns the full pattern match
        return $matches[0];            
    };

    var_dump
    (
        $getTruncatedValue(1.123,1),   //string(3) "1.1"
        $getTruncatedValue(1.345,2),   //string(4) "1.34"
        $getTruncatedValue(1.678,3),   //string(5) "1.678"
        $getTruncatedValue(1.90123,4)  //string(6) "1.9012"  
    );
```

- The only pitfall in this approach may be the need to use a Regular Expression (which sometimes could bring a performance penalty).

Note: It's quite hard to find a native approach to truncate decimals, and I think it's not possible to perform that using sprintf and other string-related functions.

Comment: Thanks, i want to try this one.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, I come to this solution also and this approach prevent any form of rounding data

Answer (score 4):

The answers of **RenaPot**, **IsisCode**, **goredwards** are not correct.

Because of how float works in computers (in general), float is not accurate.

To replicate the issue:

```
floor(19.99 * 100);  // Outputs 1998 instead of 1999
floor( 5.10 * 100);  // Outputs  509 instead of  510
```

Within PHP internally, `19.99 * 100` results in something like `1998.999999999999999`, which when we do `floor` of that, we get `1998`.

**Solution:**

**Solution 1:** Use **bcmath** library (Suggested by @SamyMassoud) if you have it installed (some shared hosting servers may not have it installed by default). Like so:

```
//floor(19.99 * 100);// Original
floor(bcmul(19.99, 100));// Outputs 1999
```

**Solution 2:** String manipulation (my recommendation):

```
// Works with positive and negative numbers, and integers and floats and strings
function withoutRounding($number, $total_decimals) {
    $number = (string)$number;
    if($number === '') {
        $number = '0';
    }
    if(strpos($number, '.') === false) {
        $number .= '.';
    }
    $number_arr = explode('.', $number);

    $decimals = substr($number_arr[1], 0, $total_decimals);
    if($decimals === false) {
        $decimals = '0';
    }

    $return = '';
    if($total_decimals == 0) {
        $return = $number_arr[0];
    } else {
        if(strlen($decimals) < $total_decimals) {
            $decimals = str_pad($decimals, $total_decimals, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        }
        $return = $number_arr[0] . '.' . $decimals;
    }
    return $return;
}

// How to use:
withoutRounding(19.99, 2);// Return "19.99"
withoutRounding(1.505, 2);// Return "1.50"
withoutRounding(5.1, 2);// Return "5.10"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can convert `1.505` to String data type and make use of `substring()` to truncate last character.

And again convert it in `integer`.

Comment: what if the number is 1 digit longer after comma?

Answer (score 2):

We can use bc functions if they are available:

```
echo bcadd(sprintf('%F', 5.445), '0', 2); // => 5.44
echo sprintf('%.2F', 5.445); // => 5.45
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$num = 118.74999669307;
$cut = substr($num, 0, ((strpos($num, '.')+1)+2));`
// Cut the string from first character to a length of 2 past the decimal.
/ substr(cut what, start, ( (find position of decimal)+decimal itself)+spaces after decimal) )
echo $cut;
```

this will help you shorten the float value without rounding it..

Comment: Its taken me quite a while to find this answer, it looks very promising as the solution!

Comment: but what happens if you don't know how long the decimal is and what happens if you have this scenario: 1.3E+10

Answer (score 1):

Its easy and work better.

```
$value = 12.9987876;
$value_exp = explode(".", $value);
$value_new = floatval($value_exp[0].'.'.substr($value_exp[1],0,4));

echo $value_new; // output will 12.9987
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but here is a simple solution.  Using the OP example of 1.505 you can simply use the following to get to 1.50.

```
function truncateExtraDecimals($val, $precision) {
    $pow = pow(10, $precision);
    $precise = (int)($val * $pow);
    return (float)($precise / $pow); 
}
```

This manages both positive and negative values without the concern to filter which function to use and lends to correct results without the worry about what other functions might do with the value.

```
$val = 1.509;
$truncated = sprintf('%.2f', truncateExtraDecimals($val, 2));
echo "Result: {$truncated}";

Result: 1.50
```

The sprintf is needed to get exactly 2 decimals to display otherwise the Result would have been 1.5 instead of 1.50.

Comment: return(intval($val * $pow) / $pow);

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using ceil, floor and round, just treat it as a string and cut it if necessary. This avoids all the rounding issues.

The code below looks for the first 2 numbers after the dot and singles them out. Then it looks for any numbers that trail that. It then replaces the entire thing with only the 2 numbers it found.  If number doesn't match the replace rule, nothing changes.

You could stick this in a function call and pass the function the number and the quantity of numbers you want to keep after the decimal place.

```
    // Shorten number to 2 decimal places without rounding
    $num = 2213.145;
    $num = floatval(preg_replace("/\.([0-9]{2})[0-9]{0,99}/",".$1",$num));
```

Answer (score -3):

just do `(int) $number;` to get integer

Comment: This might be a good solution if you want to drop off all the decimals.