# No Truncate function in PHP - Options?

Tags: php, decimal, truncate, floor

I have an algorithm that performs the following calculations:

1. ( ( 0.50 * 0 ) + 7 ) / 10 = 0.70
2. ( ( 0.70 * 10 ) + 9 ) / 20 = 0.80
3. ( ( 0.80 * 20 ) + 7 ) / 30 = 0.7666666667 -> I want this value to truncate to **0.76**

So that it may feed into the rest of the calculation as:

4a. ( ( **0.76** * 30 ) + 8 ) / 40 = 0.77

And **not** to feed in when rounded up two decimal places as **0.77**:

4b. ( ( **0.77** * 30 ) + 8 ) / 40 = 0.77

****The following seem to have failed and instead force a round up to 0.77:****

The PHP sptrinf() function: [PHP dropping decimals without rounding up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079158/php-dropping-decimals-without-rounding-up)

The PHP number_format() function: [Show a number to two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

The PHP floor() function: [Truncate float numbers with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668628/truncate-float-numbers-with-php)

- Is there another way?
- Is it at all possible to achieve what I want (truncate to two decimal places) with PHP?

**UPDATE - SOLVED**
Ok, it is working now thanks to dkamins and zneak. I used the floor() approach (I assume I wasn't doing something right in the past). *However, now the following happens:*

e.g.

(0.86 * 30) + 9 ) / 40 = 0.87 (it should), yet after TRUNC it = 0.86

How is it truncating 0.87 to 0.86? It makes no sense. Is there a way to get it to truncate only if there are more than 2 decimal places?

Comment: You should check out @Fernando Prieto [his answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19124167/1890400). He uses a (sub)string based approach which is similar to the first part of your chosen solution, but I personally think it might be more efficient and more robust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PHP's [floor](http://php.net/floor) function along with some decimal shifting like so:

```
floor(0.7666666667 * 100) / 100;
```

Comment: And if you find it ugly, you can make a thin wrapper around it: `function trunc($number, $places) { $power = pow(10, $places); return floor($number * $power) / $power; }`

Comment: Ok, this is too much. It appears to be working now (typical). I have used both the standard floor(num * 100) / 100 and the function (thanks zneak) and both work great and I get my 0.76. Many thanks. Yet, I have a follow-up, see-above :)

Answer (score 5):

All the answers given here round the number.
This function worked for me and i hope for you too.

```
function truncate($number, $decimals)
{
  $point_index = strrpos($number, '.'); 
  return substr($number, 0, $point_index + $decimals+ 1);
}
```

Where `$number` is the number to truncate and`$decimals` is the number of decimals you want.
*Example:* `truncate(-38.59540719940386 , 6);` returns -38.595407

If you want, check [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php/)'s documentation!

Comment: I like this function for various reasons: it's clear, easy to understand how exactly it works, no hard-to-understand magic happening. Furthermore its pretty efficient and you know 100% sure that no strange rounding errors will creep in.

Comment: This function works incorrectly with floats in expotential form ("2.5E7" for example". Also, for very small negative floating point numbers it returns strings like "-0.0000000".

Answer (score 2):

how about [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

```
  <?php
  echo round(3.4);         // 3
  echo round(3.5);         // 4
  echo round(3.6);         // 4
  echo round(3.6, 0);      // 4
  echo round(1.95583, 2);  // 1.96
  echo round(1241757, -3); // 1242000
  echo round(5.045, 2);    // 5.05
  echo round(5.055, 2);    // 5.06
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this accurately for both positive ***and*** negative numbers you need use:

- the php `floor()` function for +ve numbers
- the php `ceil()` function for -ve numbers

  function truncate_float($number, $decimals) {
  $power = pow(10, $decimals);
  if($number > 0){
  return floor($number * $power) / $power;
  } else {
  return ceil($number * $power) / $power;
  }
  }

the reason for this is that `floor()` always rounds the number ***down***, not towards zero.
ie `floor()` effectively rounds -ve numbers *towards a larger absolute value*
eg `floor(1.5) = 1` while `floor(-1.5) = 2`

Therefore for the truncate method using `multiply by power, round, then divide by power`:

- `floor()` only works for positive numbers
- `ceil()` only works for negative numbers

To test this, copy the following code into the editor of http://phpfiddle.org/lite (or similar):

```
<div>Php Truncate Function</div>
<br>
<?php
    function truncate_float($number, $places) {
        $power = pow(10, $places); 
        if($number > 0){
            return floor($number * $power) / $power; 
        } else {
            return ceil($number * $power) / $power; 
        }
    }

    // demo
    $lat = 52.4884;
    $lng = -1.88651;
    $lat_tr = truncate_float($lat, 3);
    $lng_tr = truncate_float($lng, 3);
    echo 'lat = ' . $lat . '<br>';
    echo 'lat truncated = ' . $lat_tr . '<br>';
    echo 'lat = ' . $lng . '<br>';
    echo 'lat truncated = ' . $lng_tr . '<br><br>';

    // demo of floor() on negatives
    echo 'floor (1.5) = ' . floor(1.5) . '<br>';
    echo 'floor (-1.5) = ' . floor(-1.5) . '<br>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used would use the round() function as mentioned by Kartikey. You can find more information here at [PHP.Net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

```
float round ( float $val [, int $precision = 0 [, int $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ]] )
```

Fissh

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a mode for "towards zero", so it cannot be used.