# Take off X amount of decimals from a number

Tags: php

I have let's say `0.00001004` or `0.00001`

I am trying to choose and how decimal places to prune off and turn both of those so it returns `0.00001` both times.

I do **not** want it to round the number in anyway.

I've tried this but it is not giving me the desired results.

```
function decimalFix($number, $decimals) { 
   return floatval(bcdiv($number, 1, $decimals)); 
}

echo decimalFix(0.00001, 5); // returns "0"
```

Does anyone know what I can do? I can't have any rounding involved and I need it to return it as a float and not a string.

Comment: Are you looking for `number_format` perhaps?

Comment: No because I don't want it to round @TimLewis

Comment: [PHP How do I round down to two decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277945/php-how-do-i-round-down-to-two-decimal-places)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP dropping decimals without rounding up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079158/php-dropping-decimals-without-rounding-up)

Comment: `number_format(0.000019, 5)` returns `0.00002` and not `0.00001` @TimLewis

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I don't want it to round up if it's `>=5`

Comment: Huh; you are correct. I could have sworn it didn't do that, but testing does prove otherwise. So maybe you're not looking for `number_format` exclusively.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Yeah, they did actually: "I can't have any rounding involved and I need it to return it as a float and not a string."

Comment: @meowgoesthedog you're wrong. `round(0.000018, 5, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN)` returns `0.00002` I need it to give me `0.00001`

Comment: @bryan my bad, I misread the specification for this argument (it only rounds down past the half-way point). There is a comment at the foot of [that page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php#allnotes) which gives an implementation for `round_down`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncate float numbers with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668628/truncate-float-numbers-with-php)

Comment: Why do you even want to do this in the first place?

Comment: @Sammitch I am restricted in how many decimal places but still need to keep track of the excess runoff

Comment: Ok, but *why*? You question sounds more and more like something that need to be handled *entirely differently*, but to know for sure we need to know what exactly you're doing.

Comment: This is what I NEED to do. `$number = $original_number - $truncated_number` so that I can get the excess decimal. So example `$number = 0.00001983 - 0.00001`. But I need to use the `$truncated_number` in other places so just being able to do that equation doesn't entirely help me. @Sammitch

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're so committed to losing precision, but here's some math to make that particular mistake in the way you wish to make it.

```
$derp = 0.000016;

function derp_round($derp, $len) {
    $mul = pow(10, $len);
    return floor($derp * $mul)/$mul;
}

var_dump(
    $derp,
    number_format($derp, 5),
    sprintf("%.5f", $derp),
    sprintf("%.5f", round($derp, 5, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN)),
    sprintf("%.5f", derp_round($derp, 5))
);
```

Output:

```
float(1.6E-5)
string(7) "0.00002"
string(7) "0.00002"
string(7) "0.00002"
string(7) "0.00001"
```

Comment: Note that this has the exact same float precision problem as the first function in my answer: flooring 0.29 to 2 decimals returns 0.28: https://3v4l.org/8eD8Y

Comment: @rickdenhaan ugh

Comment: Nice catch, but see where I said "losing precision"? Welcome to floating point! This is a bad idea and I don't think that there's a good reason to even *want* to do this.

Comment: Don't be mad because you can't comprehend a good reason. The fact that NO ONE on stack overflow has given a foolproof solution shows that this is infact a good question so thanks for the downvote @Sammitch

Answer (score 0):

There's a function that does *exactly* this in the [first comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php#96568) on the PHP documentation for `floor()`. I'll copy it here in case it disappears from there, but credits go to seppili_:

```
function floordec($zahl,$decimals=2){    
     return floor($zahl*pow(10,$decimals))/pow(10,$decimals);
}
```

Use it like:

```
$number = 0.00001004;

$rounded = floordec($number, 5);
var_dump($rounded); // float(0.00001)
```

**Edit**: There's a comment [further down](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php#118555) on that page by Leon Grdic that warns about float precision and offers this updated version:

```
function floordec($value,$decimals=2){    
    return floor($value*pow(10,$decimals)+0.5)/pow(10,$decimals);
}
```

Usage is the same.

Comment: The "fix" doesn't work. It rounds the float's up. But the original one does. But I'm afraid now I'll run into problems.

Comment: Turns out this question had been asked before, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28328463/1941241) from that question seems to work for all the cases I've found where the other answers here have issues with float precision.