# How to get upto two digits after decimal in PHP

Tags: php

**Sample Input**

-33.8670522

151.1977362

12.9582505

**Required Output**

-33.86

151.19

12.95

**Output that i am getting**

-33.87

151.20

12.96

Below is my code but issue is it is rounding off the last digit

```
$n_va = substr($va, 0, $va < 0 ? 3 : 2);
```

Can anybody help me with it!!!!

Comment: I would check out https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: Also check out https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP dropping decimals without rounding up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079158/php-dropping-decimals-without-rounding-up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your desired results, multiply the numbers by 100, take the [`intval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval) to truncate to the integer part and then divide by 100 again:

```
$values = array(-33.8670522, 151.1977362, 12.9582505);

foreach ($values as $value) {
    echo intval($value * 100) / 100 . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
-33.86
151.19
12.95
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/cEipm)